Multipass IP resolution failing
I am trying to deploy a basic Flask application on my Ubuntu VM through multipass. However, I cannot access the website through the IP address from the host OS on the browser.
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
 * Serving Flask app 'microblog.py'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit

curl works with the public IP address, I have enabled ufw for port 5000
aamir@Aameers-MacBook-Air hht_webapp %  curl -X GET "http://192.168.1.178:5000/"
Hello, World!% ```


ubuntu@mysql:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     LIMIT       Anywhere                  
5000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)             
5000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

ubuntu@mysql:~$ netstat -an |grep :5000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47376         127.0.0.1:5000          TIME_WAIT


looks like it's listening on 127.0.0.1:5000 ...

Yeah its working for localhost, but I cannot access the website from host OS on the browser

so, http://127.0.0.1:5000 doesn't work?
